# Identifying the boundaries of N-groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

I have spent quite some time dealing with the following:

Imagine that you have **N** number of groups with multiple records each and every record has **unique** `starting` and `ending` points.

In other words:

```
ID|GroupName|StartingPoint|EndingPoint|seq(row_number)|desired_seq
__|_________|_____________|___________|_______________|____________
1 | Grp1    |2014-01-06   |2014-01-07 |1              |1
__|_________|_____________|___________|_______________|____________
2 | Grp1    |2014-01-07   | 2014-01-08|2              |2
__|_________|_____________|___________|_______________|____________
3 | Grp2    |2014-01-08   | 2014-01-09|1              |1
__|_________|_____________|___________|_______________|____________
4 | Grp1    |2014-01-09   | 2014-01-10|3              |1
__|_________|_____________|___________|_______________|____________
5 | Grp2    |2014-01-10   | 2014-01-11|2              |1
__|_________|_____________|___________|_______________|____________
```

As you can see, the `starting point` for every consecutive record is the same as the `ending point` of the previous.

Basically, I would like to obtain the `minimumS and maximumS` for each group based on the dates. Once a record with new group name appears, then consider it as a new group and reset the sequencing.

Single `row_number()` function is not sufficient enough for this task since it doesnt reflect the change in the group names.(I have included a seq column in the sample data which represents the values generated by row number)

Desired result based on the sample data:

```
1  Grp1    |2014-01-06   |  2014-01-08  
2  Grp2    |2014-01-08   |  2014-01-09
3  Grp1    |2014-01-09   |  2014-01-10
4  Grp2    |2014-01-10   |  2014-01-11
```

What I have tried:

```
;with cte as(
select *
, row_number() over (partition by GroupName order by startingpoint) as seq
from table1
)
select * 
into #temp2
from cte t1
left join cte t2 on t1.id=t2.id and t1.seq= t2.seq-1

select * 
,(select startingPoint from #temp2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.seq= (select MIN(seq) from #temp2) as Oldest
(select startingPoint from #temp2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.seq= (select MAX(seq) from #temp2) as MostRecent
from #temp2 t1
```

Comment: Judging from the table it seems like you could just use `MIN` and `MAX` unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a `gaps-and-islands` problem with subgrouping.  The trick is grouping by the difference between two ROW_NUMBER() values, one partitioned and one unpartitioned.

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT
    GroupName,
    StartingPoint,
    EndingPoint,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY StartingPoint)
      - ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY StartingPoint) AS SubGroupId
  FROM #test
)
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(StartingPoint)) AS SortOrderId,
  GroupName                                       AS GroupName,
  MIN(StartingPoint)                              AS GroupStartingPoint,
  MAX(EndingPoint)                                AS GroupEndingPoint
FROM t
GROUP BY GroupName, SubGroupId
ORDER BY SortOrderId
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    GroupName, 
    MIN(StartingPoint) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY Id), 
    MAX(EndingPoint) OVER (PARTITION BY GroupName ORDER BY Id)
FROM table1
```

Because `partition` does not lead to the reduction of number of rows there will be originally duplicated entries, which are removed with `distinct`.

Answer (score 0):

This is *so* much easier with the `lag()` functionality in SQL Server 2012.  The way I approach these problems is to find where groups start, assigning a flag of 1 or 0 to each row.  Then take a cumulative sum of the `1`s to get a new group id.

In SQL Server 2008, you can do this with correlated subqueries (or joins):

```
with table1_flag as (
      select t1.*,
             isnull((select top 1 1
                     from table1 t2
                     where t2.groupname = t1.groupname and
                           t2.endingpoint = t1.startingpoint
                    ), 0) as groupstartflag
      from table1 t1
     ),
     table1_flag_cum as (
      select tf.*,
             (select sum(groupstartflag)
              from table1_flag tf2
              where tf2.groupname = tf.groupname and
                    tf2.startingpoint <= tf.startingpoint
             ) as groupnum
      from table1_flag tf
     )
select groupnum, groupname,
       min(startingpoint) as startingpoint, max(endingpoint) as endingpoint
from table1_flag_cum
group by groupnum, groupname;
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have tested the query [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87a45/2), however I am not able to adjust it as per my reuirements. Your query returns 07-10 for Grp1 and 08-11 for Grp2, which means that grps 2 is included in grp1

Comment: @Kiril . . . It is including the `groupname` in every comparison, including the final `group by`.  The groups should not be interfering with each other.

Comment: Well.This is what I would expect but, I am still geting multiple Groups associated with the same date period.

Comment: I guess, my question is a bit missleadnig. Essentially what I want is to flag the row as a new group every time when the previous row contains different GroupName. Also, if there is a new row containing the exact same GroupName as any of the previous rows, consider it as new group.